# insert checked checkbox values into text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with 3 arrays of checkboxes - hummus[], mayo[], jam[]. In the jquery functions below, when the required number of checkboxes are checked the rest of the checkboxes are disabled (this currently works).

**Question**: As they are checked, I am also trying to get the checked checkbox values into text field values, hummus1, hummus2, mayo1, jam1 - (these text fields will change to hidden fields for posting when live).
The 2 hummus functions don't work and the mayo and jam functions only return the first checkbox value of the array whether checked or not.

Any help here is much appreciated.

```
jQuery(function one(){
var max = 2;
var checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"][name="hummus[]"]');

checkboxes.change(function(){
var current = checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
checkboxes.filter(':not(:checked)').prop('disabled', current >= max);

// Trying to insert the 2 checked hummus values from the hummus array into text fields
$('input[type="text"][name="hummus1"]').val($('input[type="checkbox"][name="hummus[0]"]').val());
$('input[type="text"][name="hummus2"]').val($('input[type="checkbox"][name="hummus[1]"]').val());
});
});

jQuery(function two(){
var max = 1;
var checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"][name="mayo[]"]');

checkboxes.change(function(){
var current = checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
checkboxes.filter(':not(:checked)').prop('disabled', current >= max);

// Trying to insert the single checked mayo value into the mayo1 text field
$('input[type="text"][name="mayo1"]').val($('input[type="checkbox"][name="mayo[]"]').val());
});
});

jQuery(function three(){
var max = 1;
var checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"][name="jam[]"]');

checkboxes.change(function(){
var current = checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
checkboxes.filter(':not(:checked)').prop('disabled', current >= max);

// Trying to insert the single checked jam value into the jam1 text field
$('input[type="text"][name="jam1"]').val($('input[type="checkbox"][name="jam[]"]').val());
});
});

jQuery(function uncheck() {
// Uncheck all checkboxes on page load    
$(':checkbox:checked').removeAttr('checked');
})
```

The HTML:

```
<form id="orderProductForm219" name="orderProductForm219" method="post">
<b>Select any TWO Hummus from this list.</b> 
<br /><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="hummus[]" value="chilli hummus with harissa"> chilli hummus with harissa<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="hummus[]" value="cumin &amp; lemon oil hummus"> cumin &amp; lemon oil hummus<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="hummus[]" value="garlic hummus"> garlic hummus<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="hummus[]" value="pumpkin, fetta &amp; dukkah hummus"> pumpkin, fetta &amp; dukkah hummus
<br /><br />
<b>and include ONE Mayonnaise from this list.</b> 
<br /><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="mayo[]" value="aioli"> aioli<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="mayo[]" value="saffron, dill &amp; mustard mayonnaise"> saffron, dill &amp; mustard mayonnaise<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="mayo[]" value="wasabi mayonnaise"> wasabi mayonnaise<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="mayo[]" value="chilli mayonnaise"> chilli mayonnaise<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="mayo[]" value="caesar dressing"> caesar dressing<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="mayo[]" value="smoked aioli"> smoked aioli
<br /><br />
<b>and include ONE Relish, Jam, Curd or Pesto from this list.</b> 
<br /><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="jam[]" value="middle eastern red pepper &amp; pomegranate pesto"> middle eastern red pepper &amp; pomegranate pesto<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="jam[]" value="aubergine relish"> aubergine relish<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="jam[]" value="beetroot relish"> beetroot relish<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="jam[]" value="tomato &amp; chilli relish"> tomato &amp; chilli relish<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="jam[]" value="taramasala"> taramasala<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="jam[]" value="preserved lemons"> preserved lemons<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="jam[]" value="rasberry &amp; white chocolate jam"> rhubarb, rasberry &amp; white chocolate jam<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="jam[]" value="apricot, saffron &amp; vanilla bean jam"> apricot, saffron &amp; vanilla bean jam<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="jam[]" value="apricot &amp; armaretto jam"> apricot &amp; armaretto jam<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="jam[]" value="rose water &amp; cardamon marmalade"> rose water &amp; cardamon marmalade<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="jam[]" value="whiskey &amp; ginger marmalade"> whiskey &amp; ginger marmalade<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="jam[]" value="lemon curd"> lemon curd<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="jam[]" value="Lemon &amp; passion fruit curd"> lemon &amp; passion fruit curd
<br />
<input type="hidden" name="productId" value="219" />
<input type="hidden" name="productTitle" value="Gift Pack" />
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="1.00" />
<input type="text" name="hummus1" id="hummus1" value="" />
<input type="text" name="hummus2" id="hummus2" value="" />
<input type="text" name="mayo1" id="mayo1" value="" />
<input type="text" name="jam1" id="jam1" value="" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the changes I made and see if you understand what is going on. This code works fine for me in my [demo](http://cssdeck.com/labs/hp9a8met). You didn't need to wrap each change function in its own function you just need to set each action up in the document ready function.

HTML:

```
<form id="orderProductForm219" name="orderProductForm219" method="post">
    <b>Select any TWO Hummus from this list.</b> 
    <br /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="hummus[]" value="chilli hummus with harissa"> chilli hummus with harissa<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="hummus[]" value="cumin &amp; lemon oil hummus"> cumin &amp; lemon oil hummus<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="hummus[]" value="garlic hummus"> garlic hummus<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="hummus[]" value="pumpkin, fetta &amp; dukkah hummus"> pumpkin, fetta &amp; dukkah hummus
    <br /><br />
    <b>and include ONE Mayonnaise from this list.</b> 
    <br /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="mayo[]" value="aioli"> aioli<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="mayo[]" value="saffron, dill &amp; mustard mayonnaise"> saffron, dill &amp; mustard mayonnaise<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="mayo[]" value="wasabi mayonnaise"> wasabi mayonnaise<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="mayo[]" value="chilli mayonnaise"> chilli mayonnaise<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="mayo[]" value="caesar dressing"> caesar dressing<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="mayo[]" value="smoked aioli"> smoked aioli
    <br /><br />
    <b>and include ONE Relish, Jam, Curd or Pesto from this list.</b> 
    <br /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="jam[]" value="middle eastern red pepper &amp; pomegranate pesto"> middle eastern red pepper &amp; pomegranate pesto<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="jam[]" value="aubergine relish"> aubergine relish<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="jam[]" value="beetroot relish"> beetroot relish<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="jam[]" value="tomato &amp; chilli relish"> tomato &amp; chilli relish<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="jam[]" value="taramasala"> taramasala<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="jam[]" value="preserved lemons"> preserved lemons<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="jam[]" value="rasberry &amp; white chocolate jam"> rhubarb, rasberry &amp; white chocolate jam<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="jam[]" value="apricot, saffron &amp; vanilla bean jam"> apricot, saffron &amp; vanilla bean jam<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="jam[]" value="apricot &amp; armaretto jam"> apricot &amp; armaretto jam<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="jam[]" value="rose water &amp; cardamon marmalade"> rose water &amp; cardamon marmalade<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="jam[]" value="whiskey &amp; ginger marmalade"> whiskey &amp; ginger marmalade<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="jam[]" value="lemon curd"> lemon curd<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="jam[]" value="Lemon &amp; passion fruit curd"> lemon &amp; passion fruit curd
    <br />
    <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="219" />
    <input type="hidden" name="productTitle" value="Gift Pack" />
    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="1.00" />
    <input type="text" name="hummus1" id="hummus1" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="hummus2" id="hummus2" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="mayo1" id="mayo1" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="jam1" id="jam1" value="" />
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').removeAttr('checked');

    var checkboxesH = $('input[type="checkbox"][name="hummus[]"]');  
    checkboxesH.change(function()
    {
        var max = 2;
        var current = checkboxesH.filter(':checked').length;

        checkboxesH.filter(':not(:checked)').prop('disabled', current >= max);

        // Trying to insert the 2 checked hummus values from the hummus array into text fields
        var hummus1Val = $(checkboxesH.filter(':checked').get(0)).val();
        $('input[type="text"][name="hummus1"]').val(hummus1Val);
        var hummus2Val = $(checkboxesH.filter(':checked').get(1)).val();
        $('input[type="text"][name="hummus2"]').val(hummus2Val);
    });

    var checkboxesM = $('input[type="checkbox"][name="mayo[]"]');
    checkboxesM.change(function()
    {
        var max = 1;
        var current = checkboxesM.filter(':checked').length;

        checkboxesM.filter(':not(:checked)').prop('disabled', current >= max);

        // Trying to insert the single checked mayo value into the mayo1 text field
        var mayo1Val = checkboxesM.filter(':checked').val();
        $('input[type="text"][name="mayo1"]').val(mayo1Val);
    });

    var checkboxesJ = $('input[type="checkbox"][name="jam[]"]');
    checkboxesJ.change(function()
    {
        var max = 1;
        var current = checkboxesJ.filter(':checked').length;
        checkboxesJ.filter(':not(:checked)').prop('disabled', current >= max);

        // Trying to insert the single checked jam value into the jam1 text field
        var jam1Val = checkboxesJ.filter(':checked').val();
        $('input[type="text"][name="jam1"]').val(jam1Val);
    });
});
```

Comment: You don't even need to do a remove of all checks on load... they will always be loaded unchecked.